# IOS Dev Fetching JSON Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, dictionary

I am a novice at IOS dev and i really need some help.

I want to parse (which is working) and fetch some JSON Data.
i used this tutorial for the http request and json parsing 
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/04/ios-http-request-and-json-parsing.html

everything works fine with a 1 dimensional dictionary

but I need to be able to fetch the following JSON Data

```
[{"defaultGateway": "10.10.10.254", "hostname": "On", "connected": "true", "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255", "iPAddress": "10.10.10.10", "dhcpEnabled": "true"},
{"defaultGateway": "10.10.10.254", "hostname": "On", "connected": "true", "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255", "iPAddress": "10.10.10.10", "dhcpEnabled": "true"}]
```

after I use the following function I got the following dictionary which I really don't know how to access

```
NSDictionary * res = [NSJSONSerialization
                   JSONObjectWithData:data
                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                   error:&error];
```

here is a picture of the dictionary
http://www11.pic-upload.de/09.11.14/5n4hdg3eh84q.png

How can I access for example the defaultGateway in the first dictionary?

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then observe that a JSON array maps to an NS(Mutable)Array, and a JSON object maps to an NS(Mutable)Dictionary.  NSArray dumps, from NSLog, are bracketed by `()`, while NSDictionary dumps are bracketed by `{}`.  Now look at an NSLog dump of `res` and tell me what you have.  (The debugger display is deceptive.)

Comment: I got the following dump using NSLog http://www11.pic-upload.de/09.11.14/xp5sttdy3u2m.png

Comment: And you'll see that the "outermost" brackets are `()`, meaning that the outermost object is an NS(Mutable)Array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small logical error in your example. The expression `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];` returns an `NSArray` and not and `NSDictionary`. So, first you should change this part to:

```
NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

I know it's an array because your JSON string contains an array of two JSON objects. `NSJSONSerialization` will transform JSON arrays into objects of type `NSArray` and JSON objects into objects of type `NSDictionary`.

If you're not sure what your JSON contains, you can do the following:

```
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
 // do something with the array
}
else if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
 // do something with the dictionary
}
```

As for your question, you can access the data in an `NSDictionary` by providing a key, which you can do in two ways:

```
NSString *gateway = [dictionary objectForKey:@"defaultGateway"];
```

or even faster:

```
NSString *gateway = dictionary[@"defaultGateway"];
```

Coming back to your example, to access the `defaultGateway` from the first of your two JSON objects, you can do the following:

```
NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]; // parse the JSON and store in array
NSDictionary *dict = result[0]; // take the first of the two JSON objects and store it in a dictionary
NSString *gateway = dictionary[@"defaultGateway"]; // retrieve the defaultGateway property
```